# Autohotkey ClipboardAll in function does not work

Tags: copy, clipboard, autohotkey, paste

I have this script in Autohotkey and for some reason it does not work just for ClipboardAll in function:

```
global clips := Object()
copy(index){
    Send ^c
    clips[0] := ClipboardAll
}
paste(index){
    Clipboard := clips[0]
    Send ^v
}
^q:: copy(0)
!q:: paste(0)
```

but if I try the function copy with "Clipboard" then it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that AutoHotkey's arrays cannot store the contents of `clipboardAll`. Someone should report this...

Instead, if you use [pseudo arrays](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Arrays.htm#pseudo), it'll work. So you can either go for this

```
global clips0,clips1,clips2,clips3,clips4   ; ...
copy(index){
    Send ^c
    clips%index% := ClipboardAll
}
paste(index){
    Clipboard := clips%index%
    Send ^v
}
^q:: copy(0)
!q:: paste(0)
```

which is close to your solution but limited to the size of the array since you'll have to state every variable as global.

Other than that, the best way I can see would be handling everything in subroutines, not in functions. This way, all variables will be global:

```
copy:
    Send ^c
    clips%index% := ClipboardAll
return

paste:
    Clipboard := clips%index%
    Send ^v
return

^q::
    index := 0
    goSub, copy
return

!q::
    index := 0
    goSub, paste
return
```